# Can I allow only fullscreen with getDisplayMedia?

Tags: javascript, get-display-media

I am writing code for which is supposed to make screenshots of user monitor. I am using getDisplayMedia function to capture user screen and then making image from current frame in some intervals.

I call for getDisplayMedia with function:

```
await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
       audio: false,
       video: {
         displaySurface: 'monitor',
         width: { ideal: 1280, max: 1920 },
         height: { ideal: 720, max: 1080 },
       },
     });
```

It seems that setting `displaySurface` to `monitor` only sets fullscreen tab as default. User can still change it to browser tab or window. Is there any option to allow only recording of fullscreen?

I am using Brave browser (based on Chromium) on macOS Ventura.